# How can I install old HDD with Ubuntu 20.04 full disk encryption from old PC hardware(Intel) to new PC hardware(AMD)

Tags: boot, 20.04, hard-drive, encryption

I had an old PC (Intel) with a HDD encrypted with Ubuntu 20.04 full disk encryption. Unfortunately, the hardware failed. Thankfully, the HDD seems intact. So I bought a new AMD-based PC (new CPU, new motherboard).

I tried installing the old HDD in the new hardware, but it wouldn't boot. I encountered error messages, though I don't recall the exact wording. Unfortunately, I couldn't even reach the point of entering the encryption password.

How can I install the old HDD with its encrypted Ubuntu installation onto this new hardware and successfully boot the system?

Comment: The exact wording of the error messages is kind of important.

Comment: If the FDE is TPM-based it's impossible. Make sure the boot order is right. Then edit the GRUB parameters https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/1004020 , except to make sure the UUID is right not to add a parameter.

Comment: @DanielT Hi, I was using the built-in full disk encryption while I was installing Ubuntu 20.04. I am not sure if it is TPM-based or not, thank you for replying.